# Show a large history field in a control outside of a grid

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataGridView bound to a BindingList of my object

```
public readonly BindingList<Target> Targets = new BindingList<Target>();
private void BindControls()
{
    var source = new BindingSource(Targets, null);
    targetsDataGridView.DataSource = source;

    historyTextBox.DataBindings.Add(
        new Binding("Text", source, "HistoryText", true)
    );
}
```

My object (Target) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and shows changes to data as they happen.

One of the properties in my target object is `HistoryText`, this is too big to display in a grid so I've added a textBox below it.

How do I use binding to show the value from one column in the currently selected row in the grid. I tried adding master-detail binding sources but can't see how the relationship fits with my scenario. This appears to just work if the data is coming from a DataSet but not with `BindingList<Target>` or `List<Target>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't want the HistoryText to appear in the grid I set the Browsable attribute to false:

```
[Browsable(false)] 
public string HistoryText => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, from r in History select r.ToString());
```

Removing this fixed the problem. I'll just remove the column some other way.